# Правильная миграция windows 2008 r2 в ProxMox

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, миграция, proxmox

Добрый день.

Стоит задача заменить физический терминальный сервер на базе Windows 2008 R2 на его виртуальную копию. В качестве платформы для ВМ выбран ProxMox.

Исходя из вашего личного опыта и знаний - что предпочтительнее:

1. Создать пустую ВМ с 2k8r2 и настраивать ее потихоньку с нуля (ставить лицензии, заводить пользователей, разворачивать все ПО и периферию) или
2. Создать пустую ВМ с 2k8r2, на действующем сервере сделать fullbackup настроек (ПО, пользователи, лицензии, права и прочее) и накатить полученный архив на ВМ ?

Что по вашему мнению будет наиболее правильным?

И что-бы два раза не вставать: - существует-ли утилита, скрипт или что-то, что может создать карту (список) существующих пользовательских прав доступа к файлам? Какой пользователь к какой директории какой доступ имеет?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогла утилита disk2vhd и qemu-img.
Решение было найдено [здесь](http://ru-root.livejournal.com/2820996.html) и [здесь](http://it-mehanika.ru/index.php/2009-12-06-20-02-41/25-the-project/245-perenos-servera-2003-s-zheleza-na-proxmox-kvm).

Чуть более развернуто:

a)ФС_2008 - физический сервер Windows 2008 r2 / диск С: лежит на SSD 160Gb

b)VM_2008 - новый виртуальный сервер Windows 2008 r2. Из дисков доступен только D: (install CD) и E: (virtio_win_drivers CD)

На ФС_2008 при помощи disk2vhd (из пакета Sysinternals) был создан образ диска C - server.vhdx - он занял 33Гб (вместо 160Гб физического диска). Этот образ был по scp скопирован на машину с proxmox.

Затем при помощи qemu-img преобразован в .qcow2-образ:

`qemu-img convert -O qcow2 ./SERVER.VHDX /storage/images/VMID/vm-VMID-disk-2.qcow2`

Через web-интерфейс proxmox-а подключить полученный диск у меня не вышло и пришлось редактировать `/etc/pve/local/qemu-server/VMID.conf`.

Вписал туда:

`ide0: vm_storage:VMID/vm-VMID-disk-2.qcow2,format=qcow2,cache=writeback,size=150G`

После чего VM_2008 нормально стартанула. После запуска и первичной проверки были установлены драйвера virtio-устройства - память, диски и сетевые адаптеры. Дальше опять правка VMID.conf и замена `ide0` на `virtio0`. После этого повторный запуск VM_2008 и проверка быстродействия дисков при помощи hdtune.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 2):

Можно сначала перенести в esxi, а потом сконвертить диск vmdk с помощью  qemu-img в qcow2. Создать на проксмоксе KVM-виртуалку с параметрами как в исходной машине и подключить диск. С 2012 сервером получилось

Answer (score 1):

Есть хорошая утилитка  StarWindV2VConverter она умеет VHD в raw и qcow конвертить сразу.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/198808)

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, ответ вполне соответствует вопросу и является ответом.